# AWS CloudFormation: CREATE_FAILED DBSecurityGroup is not supported in this region (London)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to reapply a cloudformer template from another account but in the same region, EU-West-2 (London). When I apply the template I get the following error:

```
10:05:10 UTC+0100   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup   dbsgdefault DBSecurityGroup is not supported in this region
Client Request Token:Console-CreateStack-1bdd4259-7132-4d44-8ba9-c3e7af892413
```

The relevant part of the template is:

```
"dbsgdefault": {
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupDescription": "default"
  }
}
```

How come this can't be reapplied to the account?

Answer (score 5):

I got same error when used `eu-central-1` region. After examining [awslabs example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/04911f5d861ee1eba11f423232dcfdf1d2a2bef5/aws/services/RDS/RDS_MySQL_With_Read_Replica.yaml#L67) I assumed that in that (and probably also `cn-north-1` region) you have to not use `AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup` and use `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` within [VPCSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-vpcsecuritygroups) property instead.

Comment: True, for me switching to the resource name you suggested solved the issue.